# Airflow webserver redirects to nowhere

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to test a DAG I wrote in Astronomer/Airflow but I'm getting a really peculiar behavior that has me totally stuck.

Airflow's webserver comes up, and then after login as admin it redirects to http://localhost:8080/home which doesn’t appear to exist.

The specific error I get in the browser is ‘too many redirects’. I’m sure something is wrong in my configuration, but it’s not obvious (to me) what. Can you suggest steps for further diagnosis?

Thanks,
Keith

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I would share the resolution of this problem in case anyone else encounters it.

This problem came about while developing a DAG to test a part of our pipeline. The repo I was working with used a Dockerfile which was designed for automated testing and was not suitable for a DAG. Once I reverted to the stock Dockerfile the problem went away and I can now load localhost:8080/home just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues when the username or the password is incorrect. I am expecting you are either entering wrong login credentials or your configuration is checking some external authentication server and it is not configured correctly.